# Communicate with fragment in backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have problem with communicating between fragments. In first fragment I use listener to notify activity to open second fragment and pass him some data with Bundle. First fragment is in the backstack. Then, the second fragment opens and does some work with data. After it's finished, fragment should be closed and first fragment should be appear from backstack, but it should be notified about the changed data in second fragment. So, my question is how to notify first fragment that data is changed in second fragment?

Comment: You need the Activity hosting fragments to assist  with this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12105615/1531054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something more sophisticated for sending complex data, use Otto http://square.github.io/otto/ or EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus.
Or you can use the `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no direct way to communicate among `Fragment`s, And you have to communicate with its parent `Activity` to achieve your communication target. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), the official documents has told you the way to communicate among `Activity`s and `Fragment`s.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have an `Activity` that has two `Fragments`. So when you go from **FragA** -> **FragB** -> **FragA**, you're always within the same `Activity`, even though hitting the back button from **FragB** brings up **FragA**.

So, what I did to pass state, was keep that state on the `Activity`, since the `Activity` doesn't get torn down, just the `Fragments` do.  So the state is present even after hitting the back button from **FragB** -> **FragA**.