# Send message to previous fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragmnent.Say fragment A and fragment B.Now after clicking on certain button in fragment A I am starting fragment B using below code

```
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.framelayout, companyDetailsFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

Now I have another back button in fragment B.After clicking that button
I am removing that particular fragment using below code

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack()
```

Now what I want is when the user click on back button I want to pass some certain data to previous fragment A.And the problem is

`onStart()` method is not getting called,so I am not getting any values.
So how to get the data?Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can get data also in `OnResume()` of Fragment

Comment: refer this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103953/how-to-pass-result-from-second-fragment-to-first-fragment

Comment: @prshntjjl_android I am tried OnResume() also.But not working

Comment: then sorry soham, So I need R &  D for that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to solve it.Here is my answer

1.Create an interface

```
public interface OnButtonPressListener {
    public void onButtonPressed(String msg);
}
```

2.Implemented this in Fragment B

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            buttonListener = (OnButtonPressListener) getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onButtonPressed");
        }
    }

 back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
               buttonListener.onButtonPressed("Message From First Fragment");
            }
        });
```

3.Used that listener in the Activity class

```
public class ParentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnButtonPressListener { 
@Override
    public void onButtonPressed(String msg) {
        FragmentA Obj=(FragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout);
        Obj.setMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

4.Created the method in Fragment A class

```
public void setMessage(String msg){
       System.out.print("got it");
    }
```

Got the reference from [this](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/) .Hope this will help others.If anyone has other good solution please answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Store the value you want to pass in a globally scoped variable (SharedPrefs, using a singleton accessible from your Application class, etc).
2. Start a new instance of your Fragment, and include the variable as a Intent Extra.

AFAIK, there is not a way to add extras to a fragment when starting from the stack (you would access this in the onResume() if the variable could be passed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I don't want to use any globalvariable as it's a bad practice. And creating any new instance isn't a good idea i think.Though thanks for your help