# Fragment to Fragment communication fails using LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, localbroadcastmanager

I am having a problem transfering data from one fragment to another using LocalbroadcastManager.

FragmentA has editText and onclick on it will launch FragmentB.
FragmentB has a list of items and onclick on each item I want to pass the data to FragmentA.

Here is my implementation.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String highSchoolName = intent.getStringExtra("HighSchoolName");
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("HighSchoolEvent"));
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}
```

Below is Fragment B where broadcast message is sent from.

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    mHighSchoolListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            HighSchool highSchoolItem = mHighSchoolAdapter.getItem(position);
            sendHighSchoolItemToSignupForm(highSchoolItem);
        }
    });

    private void sendHighSchoolItemToSignupForm(HighSchool highSchoolItem) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("HighSchoolEvent");
        intent.putExtra("HighSchoolName", highSchoolItem.getName());
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Debug / Logging never hits the onReceive message of Broadcast receiver. Is there anything missing?
Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Because navigating from fragment A to fragment B makes fragment A's `onDestroyView()` to be called, thus unregistering the receiver.

Comment: @babs Have you replace FragmentA by FragmentB or add?

Comment: @JRamesh, I did a transaction replace.

Comment: @azizbekian, so what is the solution ?

Comment: @Babs use transaction add

Comment: @Babs Due to replace transaction it  destroy view of FragmentA

Comment: add your fragment transaction code .

Comment: @Babs If This is not working then share handling of onBackPressed() in Activity

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12103953/1083957) is very similar to your question.

Comment: Thanks @JRamesh, your suggestion of using transaction add did help.

Comment: Thanks @JRamesh and everyone for your valuable suggestion, I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "launch" means you are replacing `Fragment A` with `Fragment B`, then you are going wrong..

You should add `Fragment B` to `backstack`

```
FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(String fragmentName);
```

and you should do

`FragmentTransaction#add()`

instead of

`FragmentTransaction#replace()`

**Add**: will add another Fragment View to container

**Replace**: will replace all the contents of a container with another Fragment

I am sure you are replacing `Fragment A` with `Fragment B` and in that case your `Fragment A` will get destroyed and `Fragment B` will be loaded, you wont be able to listen to updates anymore in `Fragment A`

Answer (score 0):

As J Ramesh suggested, by changing the fragment transaction type from `replace` to `add`, fixed the issue.

Here is the fragment transaction.

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentA())
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define InterFace In Fragment B

   #### To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its `onAttach() lifecycle` method and can then call the Interface methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

```html
    UpdateFragmentA update;
    public interface  UpdateFragmentA {
       
        public void update_fragment(String data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            update= (UpdateFragmentA ) getActivity();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



// set setOnItemClickListener for List View
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
       update.update_fragment(items[position]);
    }
});
```

#### In order to receive event callbacks from the fragment, the activity that hosts it must implement the interface defined in the fragment class.

```html
 public static class MainActivity extends Activity
            implements FragmentB.UpdateFragmentA{
        ...

        public void update_fragment(String data) {
            // The user selected the Item 

            // send that data to fragment A
            a.recieve(data);  //a is FragmentA reference a=new FragmentA();
        }
    }
```

#### The host activity can deliver messages to a fragment by capturing the Fragment instance

#### In FragmentA Define Method recieve(String s);

```html
   public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
   ....
   ...
   
   public void recieve(String s)
    {
      //You get Selected Item From FragmentB through Activity
            // Do something here to display that

        if(!s.isEmpty())
        {
          textview.setText(s);
        }

    }
    
 }
```

[image]